# How to create a virtual MIDI device

Tags: port, virtual, midi

I have to write an application (like a step sequencer or arpeggiator) that sends MIDI note to a generic [DAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) , so I think that only way to implement such thing is to create a virtual MIDI device that should be recognised as a MIDI input/output interface by the OS.

I was wondering if this could be developed using [Portmidi](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/) or if I need something more complicated.

OS X support is a must, Linux and Windows support is a nice to have.

Comment: [Mido (in Python) can do this](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#virtual-ports). It uses RtMidi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Portmidi's design is based on the Windows MIDI API, which does not allow applications to create virtual ports (without installing a separate driver).

On OS X, you can create a virtual port with [MIDISourceCreate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/MIDIServices/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MIDISourceCreate); on Linux, by creating a port with the (SUBS_)READ/WRITE flags.

If you want to use a portable library, try [RtMidi](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/), which supports virtual ports on all platforms that have them.

Comment: in case somebody doesn't know it, it's not possible to use rtMidi on windows to create virtual ports ( I didn't )

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, check out the [virtual MIDI driver written by Tobias Erichsen](http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/rtpmidi.html).  While he hasn't published the API, if you e-mail him he will work something out with you.  It's very simple to work with and allows creation of MIDI ports directly from your application.